# Retrieve the seed phrase using a private key?

Tags: python

i have my private key and i'm trying to get the seed phrase from it so i can import it into metamask. how would i do that using python - either eth_account/web3/etc? Or is there another way? Or how am i supposed to import it to metamask/other wallet apps when they require a seed phrase and not a private key lol

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

Private key and seed phrase aren't interchangeable. The seed phrase is just a human-readable representation of your private key.

But, you can import a new wallet using only private key. Metamask has the option to "import wallet with private key" or something similar.

Comment: ```Metamask has the option to "import wallet with private key" or something similar.```

You can only import with a secret recovery phrase initially

Comment: Not entirely sure. I have the option to import any wallet with private key.

Comment: @user116130 You can just generate a new mnemonic within Metamask to initialize it. Once that's done, you have the option to import individual private keys. Simply ignore the mnemonic-based accounts